# Need help in jquery Call back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a button , in its click i will call a function which will open a popup with OK and CANCEL button. And click of these button the first function which i called to open the div should return true or false respectively. below is what i want.

```
<a id="button"> click me </a>

    $("#button").click(function(e){
         if(openPopUp()){

         }
    });

    function openPopUp()
    {
        // this will opean a popUpwith OK n Cancel and onclick of Ok this function should return true and false if its Cancel
    }
```

Comment: show whole code or make a fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript `confirm` dialog, like  following `confirm("Popup example")` when user click on **OK** it will return `true` else on clicking **Cancel** button it will return `false`.

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#button").click(function(e)
{
    if(openPopUp())
    {
         alert('OK clicked');       
    }
});

function openPopUp()
{
    return confirm("Please enter your name");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="button"> click me </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function AlertIt() {
var answer = confirm ("Please click on OK to continue.")
if (answer)
window.location="http://www.continue.com";
}
</script>
```

```html
<a href="javascript:AlertIt();">click me</a
```

you can try this one:

```
function demo(e, el){
  alert(this);
  alert(e);
  alert(el);
}

/* this = "hey"
 * e = "there"
 * el = "!"
 */
demo.call("Hey", "there", "!");
```

Or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AlertIt() {
var answer = confirm ("Please click on OK to continue.")
if (answer)
window.location="http://www.continue.com";
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:AlertIt();">click me</a>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/bHqSR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved easily using `confirm`

The snippet shows how to do this with the `confirm` code. You then just put your `true` code inside the `if` statement.

This put all script into ONE easy to manage function

```js
$("#button").click(function(){    
if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
  //put code for true here
  $(".test").css("background-color", "red");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Hello World</div>
<button id="button">Button</button>
```